# Reworking Gannt-chart to show years and months

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I can't figure out how to change my Gannt chart to display years and all 12 months in the year.  This is how I imagine it looking. The years and numbers are manually inputted with the timeline doesn't add up, but its just to show how I'm imagining it:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/g51hz1en9i0xk437a6xhu/ganntv.2.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=bicoyffb9ezknlz5dt4dzabop

And this is what I got now:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/14id1oxgntxocuzs5cgnd/gannt.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=9is89pneb7uwwhjejh4n209bg

Instead of displaying the year as it is now (with 8 boxes all displaying the same year, 2021), I want two boxes displaying 2021 and 2022 (if that adds up for the dates for the tasks). Below that I want each month for the year and then below that, the timeline for the different tasks (as it is now, so no tweaking here)

I still want to maintain the "Display month" function, which is supposed to fast foward the gannt chart, according to which month number you choose to input. Say I input "3" in the field. The gannt chart will start at "march" as it is the 3rd month.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried elaborating a bit more :)

Answer (score 0):

To change your Gantt chart to display years and all 12 months, you will need to modify the way the chart is set up. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. First, you need to add a new data series for the years and months. This can be done by going to the chart data and adding a new column for the years and another column for the months.
2. Next, you need to modify the X-axis of the chart to display the years and months. To do this, right-click on the X-axis and select "Format Axis". In the "Axis Options" tab, set the "Axis Type" to "Text axis" and then click on the "Edit" button next to the "Text axis labels" field. In the "Edit Series" dialog, select the columns that contain the years and months data.
3. Finally, you will need to modify the "Display month" function to take into account the years and months data. This will likely involve modifying the formulas or code that are used to generate the chart.

In my experience, [Creately gantt chart maker](https://creately.com/lp/gantt-chart-maker-online/) can use to visualize the timelines better. Now It has the data integration feature which makes it a more advanced tool to use.